# C# - Exception when trying to set a ListView DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I'm trying to set a ListView's Data Source using a LINQ query. It does set the DataSource as expected when I look into my ListView while debugging, however it does not update on my web form.

My Web form list view:

```
<asp:ListView ID="SampleDisplayControl" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>   
                            <audio src='<%# Eval("Url") %>' controls="" preload="none"></audio>                                
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Literal ID="label" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server"/>                                     
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

My backend:

```
try
        {

            SampleDisplayControl.DataSource = from o in getSampleGalleryContainer().GetDirectoryReference("samples").ListBlobs()
                                              select new { Url = o.Uri, Title = GetTitle(o.Uri) };

            SampleDisplayControl.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
```

The exception being thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.Web.Extensions.dll

Also a bunch of threads are exited:

> The thread ###### has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I'm not sure why this isn't working, as In a similar project I used this exact code before with no issues.

Comment: Where do you see the exception? In your code it's handled, so should not interrupt your page loading. The form is not updates probably because "provide sorting, updating, deleting, and paging functionality by using the appropriate event" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview?view=netframework-4.7.2#binding_to_a_data_source. I'd recommend you to use LinqDataSource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource?view=netframework-4.7.2 in the middle, instead of direc assignment of LINQ ecpression result.

Comment: I found what it was, I needed to set placeholders in the <LayoutTemplate>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was my html. I needed to set placeholders in the layout template and the  and label into the . A silly mistake as I misunderstood how to organize the layout.

```
<LayoutTemplate>
                            <audio id="itemPlaceholder" controls="" preload="none" runat="server"></audio>                               
                            <asp:Literal ID="labelPlaceholder" runat="server"/>                                        
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>                           
                            <audio src='<%# Eval("Url") %>' controls="" preload="none"></audio>
                            <asp:Literal ID="label" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"/>                                                                
                        </ItemTemplate>
```